# Using rails-event-store without actually storing the events?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, event-driven, rails-event-store

I know it's called rails **event-store**, but I was wondering if it's possible to use the gem for the pub/sub-style features, without an obligation to actually **store** the events?

I'm just looking to decompose by monolith into parts and improve the boundaries using the event-driven style, but I don't need to replay events or do event-sourcing etc. Add to that the fact that I don't think it's a good idea to store such events in a relational data store.

I wasn't able to find anything in the docs about this, so does anyone know of it's possible?